# temporarily stop some service while other service is starting

Tags: systemd, services

I have two services, one core service and one service that essentially overwatches the core service. Their lifetimes are specified as follows:

- the overwatch service should be started when the core service starts
- the overwatch service should stay alive when the core service goes down

Implementing these constrains as two systemd services was straightforward by simply having two independent services, with `core` also starting `overwatch`:

`core.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Core Service
Wants=overwatch.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/some/core/executable

# ...
```

`overwatch.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Overwatch Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/some/overwatch/executable

# ...
```

However, I have **another constraint**: During the startup of `core`, the `overwatch` service cannot be alive. My attempted solution was to stop `overwatch` immediately before starting `core` and starting `overwatch` again afterwards. For this I attempted to add a `ExecStartPre` and a `Before` directive to the `core` service like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Core Service
Wants=overwatch.service
Before=overwatch.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/some/core/executable
ExecStartPre=+systemctl stop overwatch.service

# ...
```

Now `overwatch` still stays alive if `core` dies, but it also successfully gets stopped right before `core` is started again. However, I expected systemd to also start it again after successfully starting `core` due to the `Wants` and `Before` directives. **But this does not happen**.

What *does* work is manually starting it again in an `ExecStartPost` directive:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Core Service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/some/core/executable
ExecStartPre=+systemctl stop overwatch.service
ExecStartPost=+systemctl start overwatch.service

# ...
```

but I was wondering if there was a better way. Preferably a recommended and descriptive way to express my requirements, rather than (ab)using pre- and post-start hooks to manually stop and start another service.

Comment: Maybe `Conflicts=overwatch.service` will work.  While documentation sounds like `Conflicts=` and `Wants=` are simple opposites, I wonder if `Conflicts=` will be handled first, stopping `overwatch.service` when `core.service` starts, then core's `Wants=` will be started when core's `Before=` trigger happens.  However an implicit `ConflictedBy=` which gets created in `overwatch.service` may just stop `core.service` afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to do the worst of both worlds: not starting `overwatch` after `core` has started, and stopping `core` if `overwatch` is started manually.